# Creating method to use one foreach instead multiple

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with c#, and I have working code where I repeated same code every line, and that's because I'm creating list, conversions , extracting data  etc.

So I have multiple `foreach` clauses,multiple `lists`, multiple conversions of `list` to `datatables`. My question is, what can I do to re-factorize this in order to have clean code?

Code:

```
private void BtnLoadReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var db = new SQLDataMgr();

   List<string> DesignStatusList = new List<string>();
   List<string> ShopStatusList = new List<string>();
   List<string> CustomerTypeList = new List<string>();
   List<string> CustomerList = new List<string>();
   List<string> ResellerList = new List<string>();
   List<string> StateList = new List<string>();
   List<string> ProjectManagerList = new List<string>();
   List<string> SalesRepresentativeList = new List<string>();

   var checkedDesignStatus = cboDesignStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
   var checkedShopStatus = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
   var checkedCustomerType = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Check       
   var checkedCustomer = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
   var checkedReseller = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
   var checkedState = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
   var checkedProjectManager = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);
   var checkedSalesRepresentative = cboShopStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);

   foreach (var i in checkedDesignStatus)
   {
      DesignStatusList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedShopStatus)
   {
      ShopStatusList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedCustomerType)
   {
      CustomerTypeList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedCustomer)
   {
      CustomerList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedReseller)
   {
      ResellerList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedState)
   {
      StateList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedProjectManager)
   {
      ProjectManagerList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   foreach (var i in checkedSalesRepresentative)
   {
      SalesRepresentativeList.Add(i.Text);
   }
   DataTable designStatusParameters = ToStringDataTable(DesignStatusList);
   DataTable shopStatusParameters = ToStringDataTable(ShopStatusList);
   DataTable customerTypeParameters = ToStringDataTable(CustomerTypeList);
   DataTable customerParameters = ToStringDataTable(CustomerList);
   DataTable resellerParameters = ToStringDataTable(ResellerList);
   DataTable stateParameters = ToStringDataTable(StateList);
   DataTable projectManagerParameters = ToStringDataTable(ProjectManagerList);
   DataTable salesRepresentativerParameters = ToStringDataTable(SalesRepresentativeList);
}
```

Comment: You might want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don’t need the for each es at all. Simply use `Where`, `Select` and ` ToList`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `ToStringDataTable` to an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Then:

```
var designStatusParameters = cboDesignStatus.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked)
    .Select(i => i.Text).ToList().ToStringDataTable();
```

You can even write the extension method for your control in a way that performs filtering, projection and converting to data table for you then you can have:

```
var designStatusParameters = cboDesignStatus.ToStringDataTable();
```

Comment: You can even write the method for your control class or `CheckBoxItems` in a way that perform filtering, projection and converting to data table for you then you can have → `cboDesignStatus.ToStringDataTable();`

Answer (score 5):

You can cut out all the `foreach` loops by using Linq's [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select):

For example:

```
var DesignStatusList =
    cboDesignStatus.CheckBoxItems
        .Where(x => x.Checked)
        .Select(i => i.Text)
        .ToList();
```

That will leave you with a `List<string>` containing all the `Text` properties from the checked CheckBoxes.

You could even skip declaring the list and combine that with your `DataTable` creation lines:

```
var designStatusParameters = ToStringDataTable(
    cboDesignStatus.CheckBoxItems
                .Where(x => x.Checked)
                .Select(i => i.Text)
                .ToList());
```

I would suggest putting this in a method of its own rather than repeating this over and over for each group of checkboxes.

Just keep in mind that less lines of code doesn't mean faster performance. It still has to iterate through the lists to find the right values. But it is much more readable than being hit in the face with a wall of repetitive code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those many `foreach` rather re-factor to a single method like

```
public void AddToList(List<string> listToAdd, List<CheckBox> listToIterate)
{
  foreach (var i in listToIterate)
  {
    listToAdd.Add(i.Text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking unnecessary expicit steps making your code way more verbose than it should be.

You are doing in separate steps:

1. Make an empty list.
2. Filter data
3. Iterate filtered data and add it to the empty list.

When you can do:

```
var newList = 
 someCollection.Where(someFilter)
               .Select(someProjection)
               .ToList();
```

That will make the code much more readable.

And, if you are in the mood, you can even make a helper method where you pass in `someCollection`, `someFilter` and `someProjection` and returns a list of something.

Answer (score 1):

The code below isn't quite right, but I'd recommend that you build one generic method that returns a DataTable and you call that method over and over.  Something like this:

```
    public DataTable getDataTable( CheckBox yourCheckBox)
    {
        DataTable returnTable = new DataTable();

        List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

        var checkedDesignStatus = yourCheckBox.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked);

        foreach (var i in checkedDesignStatus)
        {
            tempList.Add(i.Text);
        }

        returnTable = ToStringDataTable(tempList);

        return returnTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create method (maybe local method?)

```
DataTable CheckedToDataTable(YourContainerType container)
     => ToStringDataTable(container.CheckBoxItems.Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x => x.Text).ToList());
```